# Core Data versioning/migration fails with cocoa error 134190

Tags: core-data

Core data can't infere a mapping model?!
NSMappingModel *mappingModel = [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:sourceModel destinationModel:destinationModel error:&error];

Error reported
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134190.)" UserInfo=0x6b9df80 {reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible, entity=Event, property=content}

---

Xcode 4.3.3 (core data (sqlite))
This project has been set up to test versioning with different configurations to have non-user-generated content in one database with NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey set and another one with
user-generate stuff stored in the /Documents folder.

I've got a versioned core data model where version1 has one configuration(Default) and hence on database file and 2 entities in the following form.

**Configuration**
Default Event, SubEvent
**Event**
  content - NSString
  event_id - NSInteger16
  subEvents - to-Many Relationship target subEvent

**SubEvent**
  content - NSString
  subEvent_id - NSInteger16
  event - to-One Relationship target event

Version2 is changed as follows
**Configuration**
Default Event, SubEvent
Backup - SubEvent
NoBackup Event
**Event**
  content - Transformable CipherStringTransformer
  event_id - NSInteger16
  subEvents - Fetched Property - event_id = $FETCH_SOURCE.event_id

**SubEvent** 
  content - NSString
  subEvent_id - NSInteger16
  event - Fetched Property - event_id = $FETCH_SOURCE.event_id

---

If I print the corresponding properties in source-/destionationMode they look like this.

```
 po [[[[sourceModel entitiesByName] valueForKey:@"Event"] propertiesByName] valueForKey:@"content"]  
(id)(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6b9ae30>),  
name content, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Event, renamingIdentifier content, validation predicates (),  
warnings (),  
versionHashModifier (null)  
userInfo {},  
attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)  

(lldb) po [[[[destinationModel entitiesByName] valueForKey:@"Event"] propertiesByName] valueForKey:@"content"]  
(id)(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6e656b0>),  
name content, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Event, renamingIdentifier content,  
validation predicates (),  
warnings (),  
versionHashModifier (null)  
userInfo {},  
attributeType 1800 , attributeValueClassName CipherTextTransformer, defaultValue (null)
```

If I had only the switch from NSString to Transformable I would be LightWeightMigration without any interception, but with the new configurations it is impossible.